# suppress Outlook "A program is trying to access e-email address info..." Allow/Deny message

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have a desktop app written that accesses my Outlook calendar.  The only problem is that every time I run it, I have to "Allow" it through Outlook.  Is there a way to permanently suppress this message?  I understand the security implications.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA code and Outlook Programmatic Access warning](https://superuser.com/questions/1094609/excel-vba-code-and-outlook-programmatic-access-warning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [ClickYes](http://www.contextmagic.com/express-clickyes/).

> ClickYes Software is your helping hand
>   in solving issues caused by these
>   Outlook warnings. There are two
>   versions available at the moment:
>   Express ClickYes and ClickYes Pro
>   2010.