# Excel VBA code and Outlook Programmatic Access warning

Tags: microsoft-excel, email, microsoft-outlook, vba

Since about last Friday one of my Excel macros that generates an email has been getting this warning:

> Microsoft Outlook
>
> A program is trying to access e-mail address information stored in Outlook. If this is unexpected, click Deny and verify your antivirus software is up-to-date.
>
> For more information about e-mail safety and how you might be able to avoid getting this warning, click Help.
>
> Allow access for 1 minute.
>
> Allow, Deny, Help

[image]

I've narrowed it down to lines that concatenate strings to the mail object's HTMLBody property, like so:

```
.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "<br>"
```

However lines that only assign values do not trigger the warning:

```
.HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri><br>"
```

Does anyone know what caused this change in behavior?

Comment: Reading the HTMLBody property is considered a security risk, as malicious code could *read* your inbox. You might want to look at 3rd party products like Outlook Redemption.

Comment: That makes sense. I've found a workaround by composing the body in a string and writing to HTMLBody only once at the end, which looks like a better way all around. If you post what you have as the answer I will set it as the solution.

Comment: Other possibly useful answers: https://superuser.com/a/212032/577463, https://superuser.com/a/547938/577463 ■ Same question on StackOverflow: [vb.net - How can I avoid Outlook's security warning when sending email programmatically? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1052636/5267751)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the HTMLBody property is considered a security risk, as malicious code could *read* your inbox. You might want to look at 3rd party products like Outlook Redemption.

As you rightly determined, setting the property with a pre-constructed HTML string will avoid the need to read the HTMLBody property, and it will likely be more efficient too.