# "A program is trying to send an e-mail message on your behalf" warning in Outlook -> authorizing a specific program

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, bluejeans

I use [BlueJeans](https://www.bluejeans.com/) for videoconference on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. I configure BlueJeans so that it retrieves my Microsoft Outlook 2013 calendar. When I run BlueJeans, I get this warning from Microsoft Outlook:

[image]

[image]

How can I configure Microsoft Outlook so that it permanently authorizes BlueJeans to retrieve my Microsoft Outlook calendar?

---

I am [aware](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3189806/a-program-is-trying-to-send-an-e-mail-message-on-your-behalf-warning-i) that I can select the option in Microsoft Outlook:

> Never warn me about suspicious activity (not recommended)      This is the least secure setting.

in `File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Programmatic Access`

[image]

But I would prefer to authorize BlueJeans only.

Comment: Related question: [email - Excel VBA code and Outlook Programmatic Access warning - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1094609/excel-vba-code-and-outlook-programmatic-access-warning)

Answer (score 1):

I am a Technical Consultant that works at BlueJeans. Please take a look at the message beneath the "Never warn me…" option. Outlook (not BlueJeans) is showing that your Antivirus status is "Invalid" and that Outlook cannot detect the presence of any antivirus application being installed on your PC.

I have seen this a number of times before and if AV software is present on your machine please update the definitions and reboot. If your definitions are pushed by an Enterprise AV server, please ensure that the definitions on the server are up to date.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, I updated AV and rebooted the PC, I'll to keep you posted if it fixed the issue.

Comment: Great! I have read a number of articles on this topic and in some cases it can happen randomly and fixing it requires relaunching Outlook. In other cases some AV vendors do not support the mechanism that Outlook uses to detect that AV software is present. In most cases that I have seen that are specific to BlueJeans an update solves the issue, as we are a newly introduced application on the users system.

Comment: I use Avast: I upgraded it and enabled it, and after that Microsoft Outlook is showing that the Antivirus status is "valid". So far so good, I haven't seen the “A program is trying to send an e-mail message on your behalf” warning in Outlook again. I didn't expect antivirus=invalid would be the cause of this issue.